# react-redux upgrading to version 8

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, updates

I upgrade my react app to version 18 then i upgrade react-redux from 7.2.0 to version 8. after that i got this error:

Requests.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')

I take data from response when i login but it doesn't save in my store.

```
import {  createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "../reducers/combiner";


const persistConfig = {
   key: "app",
   storage,
     };

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

 const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );
 const persistor = persistStore(store);

 export { store, persistor };
```

my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
"js-base64": "^3.7.2",
"leaflet": "^1.8.0",
"leaflet-routing-machine": "^3.2.12",
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-leaflet": "^4.0.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
"reselect": "^4.1.5",
"typescript": "^4.7.2",
"uuid": "^3.4.0"
```

},

thank you in advance...

this is where i use data:

```
  useEffect(() => {
const authKey = localStorage.getItem("auth");
if (authKey === null) {
  navigate("/login");
} else {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 767) {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 600, behavior: "smooth" });
  }
  if (userInfo !== null && userInfo.data && userInfo.data.order_id !== 0) {
    navigate("/driver");
  } else if (latLon.lat === 35.6892 && latLon.lng === 51.389) {
    dispatch(sendToMapIR(latLon.lat, latLon.lng));
    dispatch(deleteRestAddress());
  }
}
}, []);
```

and this is my action:

```
export const newRequest = (
  userId,
  lat,
  lng,
  address,
  pickedItems,
  total,
  checked,
  restAddress
 ) => {
  return async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: NEW_REQUSET_WAITING });
  const result = await fetchNewRequest(
  userId,
  lat,
  lng,
  address,
  pickedItems,
  total,
  checked,
  restAddress
  );
   if (result.success) {
     return dispatch({
     type: NEW_REQUSET,
     payload: result.data
     });
    } else {
      return dispatch({
      type: NEW_REQUSET_FAILED
      });
     }
   };
  };
```

Comment: Did you get the error after updating `react-redux`? Please share the code where you fetch `data`.

Comment: yes before updating, every thing working well but after updating my application i got this error which couldn't read data.

Comment: Is `userInfo` in `if (userInfo !== null && userInfo.data && userInfo.data.order_id !== 0)` the same data that is attached to `payload` if `result.success` is true?

Comment: yes . it is the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the userInfo object looks like but maybe using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) might help:

```
if (userInfo !== null && userInfo?.data && userInfo?.data.order_id !== 0) {
    navigate("/driver");
  }
```

If not, then try to `console.log` `userInfo` and `userInfo.data` and inspect how it is.